# What video card is necessary for resnet34 64 batches?(How much memory)

Tags: hardware

I have an old nvidia gt240 and I was considering buying gt 730. However, despite being 7 years older, the gt240 is faster. Do I need at least 4g memory? Also, what card would you recommend?